# Passing 2D array as argument

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In thsi example:

```
int a[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int *p=a[0];
cout<<p;
cout<<&a[0][0];
```

Both gives the same output.
Then why am I not able to call function (say fun)like this and loop through the array:

```
fun(a[0]);

fun(int *p)
{
cout<<p[1][1];
}
```

Comment: This is not a exact duplicate but You should have a look at this excellent faq entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fun(a[0]); //this looks OK

void fun(int *p) // this is OK if you add return type'
^^^^
{
   cout<<p[1][1]; //NOT OK!  You can't have 2 indices on an `int*`
   cout << p[1]; // OK, will print a[0][1]
}
```

Comment: Very nice. To be clear, this function `fun` accesses the 1-dimensional slices of the original 2-dim array.  I don't really understand if that's what the OP wanted, so I thought best to spell that out.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:
when you write:

```
p = a[0];
```

`a[0]` (now 0th element to 1D array) actually **decays** to a pointer `p`. So both are not exactly the same type, though they appears to be. When you write:

```
fun(a[0]);
```

You are actually passing the `0`the element of the array which is now a 1D array. So you can receive in either of below ways:

```
fun(int *p); // decay to pointer to 1D array
fun(int (&a)[2]); // receive array by reference
```

In both the case `fun()` has now a 1D array.

To make the things simpler, Pass reference to array:

```
void fun(int (&p)[2][2])
{
  cout<<p[1][1];  // ok !
}
```

Usage:

```
fun(a); // not a[0]
```

Comment: No, in this case he can't pass a[0] to fun, which is apparently what he wants

Answer (score 0):

You can't `cout<<p[1][1];`, because `p` is `int *` — a one-dimensional array.